# Interact with drawings

Tags: c#, drawing, bmp

I'm using bmp but I'm open to other suggestions since I found barely any info while searching for bmp interaction.

I finally plotted my drawing into a `pictureBox`

[image]

Everything is working properly, but when i click the drawing, I'd like to read where is the pointer on the bmp. If it is above the displaying graph, I would wanna take the X position out of it.

Edit:
Another not important but interesting question:
Is it possible to stick the mouse position whenever it is above the bmp, to move only above or below the graph function?

Comment: Have a look at the MouseEventArgs parameter in your PictureBox's MouseDown event. That should get you started in the right direction.

Comment: I'm already on it, thanks anyway, I'll post a solution for all of them newbz ;)

Answer (score 0):

I've found my own answer, here :)

```
private void obterposicaonografico()
    {
        // Set the Current cursor, and display how many points in X axis you took

        this.Cursor = new Cursor(Cursor.Current.Handle);
        Cursor.Position = new Point(Cursor.Position.X, Cursor.Position.Y);
        MessageBox.Show(Cursor.Position.X.ToString());

   //Define it's position on X axis, subtracting the whole form X location
   //This will ensure that if the user moves the form around, it will still be relative to the own form
   //and not the windows positioning
        decimal posicaoX = Cursor.Position.X -this.Location.X 
        MessageBox.Show(Cursor.Position.X.ToString());




    }
```